# Save open application dimensions and positions on Windows to reopen them via configuration file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, position, dimension

Is there a way to open an application to a saved set of dimensions and positions (on Windows) via a script?  I'd also like to, of course, save the dimensions and positions of open applications -- the other side of this script.  Any suggestions?  If a script can't get this done on a Windows machine is there a way with C#/.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a User32.dll call to [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For example:

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowName);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr windowHandle, IntPtr parentWindowHandle, int x, int y, int width, int height, PositionFlags positionFlags);

    public static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);

    [Flags]
    public enum PositionFlags : uint
    {
        ShowWindow = 0x40
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var windowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad");
        SetWindowPos(windowHandle, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 640, 480, PositionFlags.ShowWindow);
    }
```

This will find the window with the title "Untitled - Notepad", move it to 0, 0, and resize it to 640x480. I have added the bare minimal number of PositionFlags and HWND flags, look at the link I provided if you require more and add them in the same way :)

Oh, and to read the dimensions out, take a look at [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Here's an example of how to use this from c#: [Example](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowrect).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`Application Settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx).

Comment: That's if I were making the application (if I understand you right).  Instead, I'm looking for a way to ask an application: "what is your dimension and position" and then later tell that same application "set your dimension and position".  I might want to have several configuration of application windows, and perhaps hotkey a script that would instantly switch between the configurations.

Comment: I don't believe that it's possible to alter a program that you haven't written (or cracked) and furthermore, I would hope that's true.

Comment: Hey @Sheridan :) I finally got my self on SO. If you look at my answer you'll see that this is actually possible, although I would hope there was a good reason to be doing it, writing a configuration window manager sounds reasonable though :) Luke